# VBA DoCmd.OpenForm Where condition Between numeric values

Tags: vba

Below is my command, I am unable to get the correct syntax for the between statement for the numeric values

```
Dim lowbsqft As Integer
Dim hibsqft As Integer


lowbsqft = Me.Building_Sqft - 500
hibsqft = Me.Building_Sqft + 500


DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", , "HomeInfo", "[Subdivision]='" & Me.Subdivision & "' AND [Bedrooms]='" & Me.Bedrooms & "' AND [Building_Sqft] Between ' & lowbsqft & ' And ' & hibsqft & '"
```

Any help is truly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly insert plain quotes `"`, this should work:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", , "HomeInfo", "[Subdivision]='" & Me.Subdivision & "' AND [Bedrooms]='" & Me.Bedrooms & "' AND [Building_Sqft] Between '" & lowbsqft & "' And '" & hibsqft & "'"
```

Comment: I tried the suggested code and it gave me runtime errror 3464 type mismatch

Comment: I tired DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", , "HomeInfo", "[Subdivision]='" & Me.Subdivision & "' AND [Bedrooms]='" & Me.Bedrooms & "' AND [Building_Sqft] Between " & lowbsqft & " And " & hibsqft & "" ... but no luck

Comment: @user4589925 can you write a sample output?

Comment: Actually the code above runs but the real problem is that the result are not appearing correctly in the subform.  The main form will indicate ex: 19 records while the subform will only display 2 .  Now if I set [Building_Sqft]=" & lowbsqft I will get ex: 10 records indicated on the main form w/ 10 displaying in the subfrom but if I set [Building_Sqft]>=" & lowbsqft  I am  back to the same problem, any ideas?  I hope I was clear